# Pattern name for a class inheriting of a generic based on itself

Tags: object-oriented-design, patterns-and-practices, generics, idioms

I'm wondering if there is a name for the pattern of defining a generic class with one type argument where the type inherits the defining class.

For example

```
public class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
}
```

I'm not sure if there even is a name for this. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be a use case for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this pattern is called *[Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)* (CRTP), at least in C++. Some call it *[Curiously Recurring Generic Pattern](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=133275)* (CRGP) or simply *Recurring Generic Types* in java. The general language independent term is *F-bound polymorphism*.

Answer (score 0):

No naming convention for this pattern exists.

- Keeping an abstract name like `T` might be fine for very small or very abstract classes.
- If the type parameter has some meaning in the business domain, consider using that name for clarity. E.g. if your business domain has a `Frobnicator` concept, you might choose the names `class AbstractFrobnicator<Frobnicator>`.
- You could also choose a name that indicates the parameter is a derived class, e.g. `Foo<Derived>` or `Foo<Self>`. I'd prefer this over `T` for larger classes.